# How to retrieve the new rows of a table every minute

Tags: mysql

I have a table, to which rows are only appended (not updated or deleted) with transactions (I'll explain why this is important), and I need to fetch the new, previously unfetched, rows of this table, every minute with a cron.

How am I going to do this? In any programming language (I use Perl but that's irrelevant.)

I list the ways I thought of how to solve this problem, and ask you to show me the correct one (there HAS to be one...)

The first way that popped to my head was to save (in a file) the largest auto_incrementing id of the rows fetched, so in the next minute I can fetch with: `WHERE id > $last_id`. But that can miss rows. Because new rows are inserted in transactions, it's possible that the transaction that saves the row with id = 5 commits before the transaction that saves the row with id = 4. It's therefore possible that the cron script retrieves row 5 but not row 4, and when row 4 gets committed one split second later, it will never gets fetched (because 4 is not > than 5 which is the $last_id).

Then I thought I could make the cron job fetch all rows that have a date field in the last TWO minutes, check which of these rows have been retrieved again in the previous run of the cron job (to do this I would need to save somewhere which row ids were retrieved), compare, and process only the new ones. Unfortunately this is complicated, and also doesn't solve the problem that will occur if a certain inserting transaction takes TWO AND A HALF minutes to commit for some weird database reason, which will cause the date to be too old for the next iteration of the cron job to fetch.

Then I thought of installing a message queue (MQ) like RabbitMQ or any other. The same process that does the inserting transaction, would notify RabbitMQ of the new row, and RabbitMQ would then notify an always-running process that processes new rows. So instead of getting a batch of rows inserted in the last minute, that process would get the new rows one-by-one as they are written. This sounds good, but has too many points of failure - RabbitMQ might be down for a second (in a restart for example) and in that case the insert transaction will have committed without the receiving process having ever received the new row. So the new row will be missed. Not good.

I just thought of one more solution: the receiving processes (there's 30 of them, doing the exact same job on exactly the same data, so the same rows get processed 30 times, once by each receiving process) could write in another table that they have processed row X when they process it, then when time comes they can ask for all rows in the main table that don't exist in the "have_processed" table with an OUTER JOIN query. But I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that such a query will consume a lot of CPU and HD on the DB server, since it will have to compare the entire list of ids of the two tables to find new entries (and the table is huge and getting bigger each minute). It would have been fast if the receiving process was only one - then I would have been able to add a indexed field named "have_read" in the main table that would make looking for new rows extremely fast and easy on the DB server.

What is the right way to do it? What do you suggest? The question is simple, but a solution seems hard (for me) to find.

Thank you.

Comment: So you have 30 consumer processes and you have to make sure each of the 30 processes consume each row only once?

Comment: @MostyMostacho good question - I want each process to consume each row AT LEAST once (I don't mind if they consume a row more than once) - And I don't care WHEN they consume it, they might consume it a minute or two late, it's fine, as long as they consume it at some point

Comment: I think I'll wait for the DVD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking on this for a while. So, let me see if I got it right. You have a HUGE table in which N, amount which may vary in time, processes write (let's call them producers). Now, there are these M, amount which my vary in time, other processes that need to at least process once each of those records added (let's call them consumers).

The main issues detected are:

- Making sure the solution will work with dynamic N and M
- It is needed to keep track of the unprocessed records for each consumer
- The solution has to escalate as much as possible due to the huge amount of records

In order to tackle those issues I thought on this. Create this table (PK in bold):

- PENDING_RECORDS(**ConsumerID**, **HugeTableID**)

Modify the consumers so that each time they add a record to the HUGE_TABLE they also add M records to the PENDING_RECORDS table so that it has the HugeTableID and also each of the ConsumerID that exist at that time. Each time a consumer runs it will query the PENDING_RECORDS table and will find a small amount of matches for itself. It will then join against the HUGE_TABLE (note it will be an inner join, not a left join) and fetch the actual data it needs to process. Once the data is processed then the consumer will delete the records fetched from the PENDING_RECORDS table, keeping it decently small.

Comment: It seems we had about the same idea :-) You have included an optimization I forgot, though: referring to the 'huge table ID' instead of copying all the fields to the 'pending records' table.

Comment: Well, if you duplicate the whole row instead of the copying all the fields... probably you would improve the consumer process by not needing to join. You will have duplicated data... but that might no be an issue. It is not only valid but probably the best way to go to duplicate data... (but YIKES, I hate so unnormalized solutions :P) The downside of duplicating is that if you later change your HUGE_TABLE table (EG: adding new columns) you will also have to change the other one, duplicating work.

Comment: The join of the secondary table with the primary table that the consumers would have to do would always be on the primary key of the primary table and for a limited number of rows (i.e. the amount of rows added to the primary table per minute). So unless the primary table is completely unmanagably huge, that join should be fast enough. So I actually prefer your solution since I also dislike data duplication :-)

Comment: Good idea, but here's the problem: How do the producer processes know how many consumers are alive at every moment? If the consumers register themselves in a database table when they start, what happens if one of them crashes, who's going to cancel that "registration" row in the db? It will stay there forever. If I can solve this problem, then I'll probably use some variation of your idea.

Comment: In that case: assign each consumer a unique ID that's a power of two. Add a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` column to the primary table. Mark a row as processed by consumer with ID X by `UPDATE primaryTable SET processed = processed | X`. Search for unprocessed rows by `SELECT * FROM primaryTable WHERE processed & X = X`. This solution would support up to 64 consumers. To support more than 64 consumers, you could play with multiple columns and some way to choose the right column. (You can also use the SET datatype, but this would mean changing the table definition for adding a new consumer ID.)

Comment: @TomasCreemers That field won't be indexable by each bit separately (as would be required for the searches to be fast)

Comment: alexk: That is just a simple synchronisation issue that the producers and consumers can solve communicating with each other. I bet in any scenario there will be time, communication and synchronisation issues and some clarifications are also missing to address them (EG: If a consumer starts is it expected to consume all the previously existing rows? If a consumer crashes, is it supposed to consume the unconsumed items once it is brought back?). I believe the best and most efficient way to go is to add communication between processes at a different level than the database.

Comment: I think the database options you have are either 'queue' unprocessed rows per consumer somehow (like @MostyMostacho and my solutions do) or mark each row as processed per consumer somehow. I think the first option is not possible for a variable number of consumers *if* they cannot be trusted to register and unregister themselves. I also think the 'best' way to implement the second option is what you described in the last paragraph of your question (a 'have_processed' table).

Comment: @MostyMostacho Direct communication between producers and consumers is impossible, since the two sets are dynamic. I believe a message queue is out of the question (if I used one, it would be to convey the db rows themselves from producers to consumers), only other solution I see is to communicate by registering/unregistering in a db table.

Comment: Thanks for the help up to now, by the way. I believe I might be able to figure something out for the remaining details.

Comment: I don't want to extend this too much (I'm also leaving now :) but if you are planning to implement this by shared memory using a database and keeping track of crashed processes you could also consider some kind of keep-alive flag in the table that would register the processes. That way you'll know that if a consumer hasn't reported back in X hours then there is some kind of issue with it and you can take appropriate action. Good luck with this!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 'best' way to do this would be to use one process that checks for new rows and delegates them to the thirty consumer processes. Then your problem becomes simpler to manage from a database perspective and a delegating process is not that difficult to write.

If you are stuck with communicating to the thirty consumer processes through the database, the best option I could come up with is to create a trigger on the table, which copies each row to a secondary table. Copy each row to the secondary table thirty times (once for each consumer process). Add a column to this secondary table indicating the 'target' consumer process (for example a number from 1 to 30). Each consumer process checks for new rows with its unique number and then deletes those. If you are worried that some rows are deleted before they are processed (because the consumer crashes in the middle of processing), you can fetch, process and delete them one by one.

Since the secondary table is kept small by continuously deleting processed rows, `INSERT`s, `SELECT`s and `DELETE`s would be very fast. All operations on this secondary table would also be indexed by the primary key (if you place the consumer ID as first field of the primary key).

In MySQL statements, this would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `consumer`(
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `consumer`(`id`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3)
-- all the way to 30
;

CREATE TABLE `secondaryTable` LIKE `primaryTable`;
ALTER TABLE `secondaryTable` ADD COLUMN `targetConsumerId` INTEGER NOT NULL FIRST;
-- alter the secondary table further to allow several rows with the same primary key (by adding targetConsumerId to the primary key)

DELIMTER //
CREATE TRIGGER `mark_to_process` AFTER INSERT ON `primaryTable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- by doing a cross join with the consumer table, this automatically inserts the correct amount of rows and adding or deleting consumers is just a matter of adding or deleting rows in the consumer table
    INSERT INTO `secondaryTable`(`targetConsumerId`, `primaryTableId`, `primaryTableField1`, `primaryTableField2`) SELECT `consumer`.`id`, `primaryTable`.`id`, `primaryTable`.`field1`, `primaryTable`.`field2` FROM `consumer`, `primaryTable` WHERE `primaryTable`.`id` = NEW.`id`;
END//
DELIMITER ;

-- loop over the following statements in each consumer until the SELECT doesn't return any more rows
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM secondaryTable WHERE targetConsumerId = MY_UNIQUE_CONSUMER_ID LIMIT 1;
-- here, do the processing (so before the COMMIT so that crashes won't let you miss rows)
DELETE FROM secondaryTable WHERE targetConsumerId = MY_UNIQUE_CONSUMER_ID AND primaryTableId = PRIMARY_TABLE_ID_OF_ROW_JUST_SELECTED;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Funny thing. We thought in the same thing :)

Comment: Good solution. So I should give each consumer a name? That sounds hard (they're just child processes) - I can give them their own PID as their name. But then if one of them crashes, someone would have to remove their name (their PID) from the `consumer` table. How can this be done in a reliable manner?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, i must say :)

1) First of all - is it possible to add a field to the table that has rows only added (let's call it 'transactional_table')? I mean, is it a design paradigm and you have a reason not to do any sort of updates on this table, or is it "structurally" blocked (i.e. user connecting to db has no privileges to perform updates on this table) ?

Because then the simplest way to do it is to add "have_read" column to this table with default 0, and update this column on fetched rows with 1 (even if 30 processess do this simultanously, you should be fine as it would be very fast and it won't corrupt your data). Even if 30 processess mark the same 1000 rows as fetched - nothing is corrupt. Although if you do not operate on InnoDB, this might be not the best way as far as performance is concerned (MyISAM locks whole tables on updates, InnoDB only rows that are updated).

2) If this is not what you could use - I would surely check out the solution you gave as your last one, with a little modification. Create a table (let's say: fetched_ids), and save fetched rows' ids in that table. Then you could use something like :

```
SELECT tt.* from transactional_table tt 
RIGHT JOIN fetched_ids fi ON tt.id = fi.row_id 
WHERE fi.row_id IS NULL
```

This will return the rows from you transactional table, that have not been saved as already fetched. As long as both (tt.id) and (fi.row_id) have (ideally unique) indexes, this should work just fine even on large sets of data. MySQL handles JOINS on indexed fields pretty well. Do not fear trying out - create new table, copy ids to it, delete some of them and run your query. You'll see the results and you'll know if they are satisfactory :)

P.S. Of course, adding rows to this 'fetched_ids' table should be ran carefully not to create unnecessary duplicates (30 simultaneous processes could write 30 times the data you need - and if you need performance, you should watch out for this case).

Comment: 1) It's possible to add a field to this table, and it's possible to update that field. But since I need each of the 30 processes to consume each row at least once, I would need a field that can quickly show me, for each consuming process, which rows it has not consumed yet. I don't think that's possible with just one extra column. Or is it? Also, I cannot create 30 extra columns, because the 30 processes might increase in number in the future and I cannot afford to create new extra columns whenever that happens.

Comment: 2) With this SQL command you provide, don't you think MySQL will need check every minute one by one all of the row ids in order to compare the two tables and find the differences? If it doesn't check all row ids one by one then how else can it do it? I think it's impossible. Am I wrong? I can check now by creating two huge tables and doing an OUTER JOIN on them, but I don't think the result will be fast (unless the row ids are cached in RAM, which could be the case when there's only one process running, but that's not satisfactory)

Comment: Having another table and adding a field both have the same problem - what happens if one of the workers "crashes" after fetching the rows.

Comment: @alexk if you need speed have you considered using some system that's designed to do queuing?

Comment: @user814064 I haven't considered it as much as I should. I'm afraid of introducing an extra point of failure (though ZeroMQ might be better at avoiding this). What would you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure the comments here are the best play to discuss it and I don't know what operating system you're using but something along that line sounds perfect.

Comment: I think Mosty Mostacho (below) posted an accurate and quite clever answer which I think does not have those issues.

Comment: @user814064 I'm using Ubuntu Linux. I'll consider it (along with the other solutions above). Which MQ would you suggest for this problem? ZeroMQ doesn't have an object-oriented library for Perl, so even though it's good I'm reluctant to use it.

Comment: MQ Series seems to be compatible with Perl and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

How about a second table with a structure like this:

source_fk - this would hold an ID of the data rows you want to read.
process_id - This would be a unique id for one of the 30 processes.

then do a LEFT JOIN and exclude items from your source that have entries matching the specified process_id.

once you get your results, just go back and add the source_fk and process_id for each result you get.

One plus about this is you can add more processes later on with no problem.

Comment: That's exactly the same as my last solution which I stated in the question (and has the same problems, and therefore has to be rejected for those same reasons).

Comment: You are correct, sorry. I had just woken up. However, I'm not sure your assumption that this approach 'will consume a lot of CPU and HD on the DB server'. If your tables are properly indexed and your query is properly designed, the load should not be any heavier on your server than a join where you include data. You can also add a timestamp filter to the searches so it only checks entries made in the last 5 minutes or so. This would greatly reduce the number of cross references. It may even help a bit to add a timestamp to this new table.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a timestamp column and use it as a reference when retrieving new rows.

Comment: timestamp will get set at the time of the INSERT query - if (for reasons only my poor database server knows) the commit takes another 2.5 minutes to complete, that row will never get consumed